# Attempt to invoke virtual method Notification Mananger

Tags: java, android, notifications

```
NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationManager;
/..onCreate
mNotificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());

/.. code
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public void CreateNotification(String code){
    NotificationCompat.Builder notifiationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    notifiationBuilder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_send)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText(code);

    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notifiationBuilder.build());
}
```

---

```
Error:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.Notification$Builder.<init>(Notification.java:2386)
    at android.app.Notification$Builder.<init>(Notification.java:2375)
    at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi24$Builder.<init>(NotificationCompatApi24.java:64)
    at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatApi24Impl.build(NotificationCompat.java:918)
    at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder.build(NotificationCompat.java:1844)
```

Comment: seems like `context` is null

Comment: If you can call `getApplicationContext()` on the current object, then it is (very likely) a `Context`. Don't try to keep a `Context` field in a `Context`. That is, change to `...new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);`.